# Can I transit in the US travelling from South Africa

Tags: usa, covid-19, south-africa

I am a citizen of Haiti, currently working in South Africa. I have to travel to Port-au-Prince for family reason. Can I transit to the US? I have B1/B2 visa and will take a covid test prior departure.

Comment: Just as a matter of grammar, your use of the words "in" and "at" are confusing.  The correct term would be "transit the US".

Answer (score 9):

No. Foreigners who have been physically present in South Africa in the 14 days before coming to the US are banned from entering the US by [Proclamation 10143](https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2021/01/28/2021-02024/suspension-of-entry-as-immigrants-and-nonimmigrants-of-certain-additional-persons-who-pose-a-risk-of). You must be able to enter the US in order to transit the US (everyone arriving in the US must immediately enter the US, even if doing an international-to-international transit; the US does not have sterile transit).

You do not fall within any of the listed exceptions. You also do not fall into the [exception](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/News/visas-news/national-interest-exception-for-certain-h-2-travelers-from-south-africa.html) for H2 workers who have been in South Africa, because you are coming to the US on B2.

Comment: Of course a way to transit is to spend over 14 days in another country which is not blacklisted **and** will allow you in. Probably not an easy task, though.